# How to return nullptr equivalent from a C++ function whose return type is pair?

Tags: c++, null, return, utility

```
pair<int, int> findEmpty(int bo[9][9], int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(bo[i][j]==0){
                return (make_pair(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
    //return nullptr; 
}
```

If nullptr can't be returned, what are the alternatives?

Comment: You can return a pair of two numbers that will symbolize that it's null.
if you want to return null you can make the function return a pair pointer.

Comment: ````return {};```` could be a solution

Comment: The alternative depends on the semantics you want. Is it an error? Maybe `throw`. Is it an "impossible" value? Maybe `make_pair(-1, -1)`. Is it an optional value that the program can work without? `std::optional<std::pair<int,int>>`. The second option is sometimes used in lieu of the third too.

Comment: Well you said your function returns two ints. So you have to either return two ints, or change it so the return type isn't two ints. Maybe try optional<pair<int, int>>

Comment: The only way your code returns in the loop will be a pair with both values zero or more.   Any pair that has either value negative can be deemed to be null e.g. `make_pair(-1, -1)`.    You may also wish to return that if `n > 8` before entering the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `optional<T>` type to represent potentially non-existent state.

If you're using C++17 this can be done with `std::optional<T>`, if you use Boost then `boost::optional<T>`, etc. You can even implement your own version of `optional`. The point is to use a semantic type that indicates that there may, or may not, be a value.

Using `std::optional` from C++17, your code becomes:

```cpp
optional<pair<int, int>> findEmpty(int bo[9][9], int n){
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(bo[i][j]==0){
                return make_pair(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return nullopt; 
}
```

---

Although you *could* solve this by returning sentinel-like values such as a pair of `(-1, -1)`, this is not a recommended practice. This forces checking for specific sentinel values on the caller, which can easily be missed or forgotten -- and may cause the bad sentinel value to find its way into other arithmetic or indirections that may never expect a negative value.

Using a semantic type to *convey* the nullability helps to prevent these sorts of errors.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 and later, you can return a `std::optional`, eg:

```cpp
std::optional<std::pair<int, int>> findEmpty(int bo[9][9], int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (bo[i][j] == 0){
                return std::make_pair(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return std::nullopt;
}

auto ret = findEmpty(...);
if (ret)
{
    // use ret.value as needed...
}
```

Alternatively, you can return a `pair<bool, pair<int,int>>`, where the `bool` indicates whether the inner `pair` is valid or not:

```cpp
std::pair<bool, std::pair<int, int> > findEmpty(int bo[9][9], int n){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (bo[i][j] == 0){
                return std::make_pair(true, std::make_pair(i, j));
            }
        }
    }
    return std::make_pair(false, std::make_pair(-1, -1));
}

std::pair<bool, std::pair<int, int> > ret = findEmpty(...);
if (ret.first)
{
    // use ret.second as needed...
}
```